# Read multiple groups of csv files from a folder and insert to respective target tables parallelly using spark or databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

**Input**:
abc.tar.gz -> un tar - > Folder: abc

**Folder structure of abc:**

root folder: abc contains csv files that are generated from 100 cities every 5 minutes in day.

Number of csv files: 100 cities * 12 files per hour * 24 hours = 28800 csv files

```
abc/    
city1_0005.csv
city1_0010.csv
..
city1_2355.csv
..
..
city2_0005.csv
city2_0010.csv
..
city2_2355.csv
..
..
city100_0005.csv
city100_0010.csv
```

**Functional Requirement:**

- Using spark/ databricks Create table for each city and load the respective city csv files (288) into table. total 100 tables will be there in target location. 1 table for 1 city.
- Each city has different schema .All columns are different for each city. so I cannot write all cities data into single table with partitions.

**technical requirement:**
Read and process the files parallelly for better performance

---

I have developed below code to process data sequentially.
I am looking for ways to optimize it .

```
staging_path="abfss://xyz/abc"

#using databricks utils  to get the list of files in folder
filesProp = dbutils.fs.ls(staging_adls_path)

#extracting the city names from list of filenames
filesSet  =set()
for file in filesProp:
    filesSet.add(file.name.split('-')[0])

#empty list to store dataframes
dictionary_df = {} 

#reading 1 city data and inserting to table
for fileName in filesSet:
    filePath = staging_path+fileName+"*"
    print(filePath)
    dictionary_df[fileName] = spark.read.options(header='True', delimiter=',').csv(filePath)
    dictionary_df[fileName].write.saveAsTable(fileName)
```

Comment: your code is already optimised. but you can change your datastructure for better performances. Just one table with a partition on the city name would be way better.

Comment: Hi Steven, I forgot mention one thing. Each city has different schema . So I cannot write all cities data into single table with partitions.

Comment: how different ? is it like totally different ? or you could have a general schema that fits all the tables but with None values where needed.

Comment: if you do not give us more input on your schema, that will be difficult to help. But otherwise, you already have the proper process.

Comment: I mean city1 csv files have a,b,c,d columns. city2 files have i,j,k,l,m,n columns. There is no common column between any of two cities schema.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve this scenario

- using a shell script to move city based csvs to / specific folders

  ```
   This will ensure the files with same schema are under same root folder
   /abc/
       city1/
            20211021/city1_0005 
            20211021/city1_0010
             ...
       city2/
            20211021/city2_0005
            20211021/city2_0010
  ```
- Since you are already on Azure and Databricks I would recommend you to use **CloudFiles** data format which will give you better performance while scanning raw files in parallel from your data lake compared to open source structured streaming + csv option
- using structured streaming with **foreachBatch()** and **Trigger(once=True)** will process only incremental files since last execution maintaining details of processed files under **checkpoint_location** path
- **process_multiple_csvs_different_schema** function accepts a microbatch and it will pick columns from respective csv file and write to corresponding city tables
- 

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

tmp_db = "test_multiple_csv_schema"
spark.sql(f"create database if not exists {tmp_db}")
base_path = <your_base_mount_path_root_folder_for_csvs>
checkpoint_location = f"{base_path}/checkpoint/multiplecsvs"
input_path = f"{base_path}/multiplecsvs/"
schema_location = f"{base_path}/schema/multiplecsvs"
staging_checkpoint_path = f"{base_path}/staging/checkpoint/multiplecsvs"
staging_data_path = f"{base_path}/staging/data/multiplecsvs"
input_format = "csv"

def process_multiple_csvs_different_schema(batch_df):

      df = (
             batch_df
                .withColumn("table",F.split(F.col("input_file_name"),"\.csv")[0])
                .withColumn("table_path",F.split(F.col("table"),"/"))
                .withColumn("table_name",F.split(F.col("table"),"/")[F.size(F.col("table_path"))-1])
                .drop("table","table_path")
          )

     list_of_cities = df.select("table_name").distinct().collect()

     list_of_cities = [city[0] for city in list_of_cities]

     for city in list_of_cities:
        print(f"processing data for {city}")
        city_df = df.where(f"table_name='{city}'")
        input_file_name = city_df.limit(1).select("input_file_name").collect()[0][0]

        df_schema = spark.read.option("format",input_format).option("header",True).load(input_file_name,format=input_format)
        select_columns = df_schema.columns

        city_df.select(select_columns).withColumn("processed_time",F.current_timestamp()).write.option("mergeSchema",True).option("mode","append").format("delta").saveAsTable(f"{tmp_db}.{city}")

raw_df = (spark
          .readStream
          .format("cloudFiles")
          .option("cloudFiles.format",input_format)
          .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation",schema_location)
          .load(input_path)
         )

(
  raw_df.withColumn("input_file_name",F.input_file_name())
        .writeStream
        .option("checkpointLocation",staging_checkpoint_path)
        .option("mergeSchema",True)
        .option("format","delta")
        .outputMode("append")
        .trigger(once=True)
        .start(staging_data_path)
        .awaitTermination()
)

staging_df = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(staging_data_path)
(
  staging_df.writeStream
     .option("checkpointLocation",checkpoint_location)
     .option("format","delta")
     .trigger(once=True)
     .foreachBatch(lambda batch_df,batch_id:process_multiple_csvs_different_schema(batch_df))
     .start()
     .awaitTermination()
)
```